# Different range ip address whit docker container restored

Tags: mysql, docker

I don't found how to change ip address in a container docker imported from other host.
Previously I save my container docker with mysql database with tar file, docker version 1.11.1, ip range 172.17.0.X (if I stop and start container ip address change). Then in the new host and same version of docker, but now the range is 172.17.42.X.
I need can manage range ip docker, but with the option "--ip=172.17.0.X" not running.
How is the way correct for this process of export-import container in different hosts??

Thans

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, when we export containers between different hosts we mustn't used ip addresses in our configuration. We have to use **link feature** to allow containers to discover each other. For example to connect two containers (mysql and webapp):

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
$ docker run --name some-app --link some-mysql:mysql -d application-that-uses-mysql
```

On the other hand if you want to use your old ip address from range 172.17.0.X  you have to add this network to new docker host before run the container

```
docker network create --subnet=172.17.0.0/24 net17

docker run --net net17 --ip 172.17.0.X -it mysql bash
```